# Data Label - Excel Bar Chart

Tags: excel, charts

I'm trying to add data labels to my excel bar chart.  eg:  `=(Sheet1!E13/Sheet1!E15)*100 (50/1000 * 100 = 5%)`, so after I've added the data lables I select the label, go to the formula bar but it does not allow me to do the calculations, it gives an error:

> The formula you typed contains an error .........

Comment: Is that the exact formula?  Just looking at it, it does contain some errors

Comment: No sorry the exact formula is:  =(Sheet1!E13/Sheet1!E15)*100  the rest is just an example of what I want to achieve

Comment: Thanks for posting the formula, I don't see an error in it.   Could E15 ever been zero (which shouldn't cause a syntax error, but would cause an error when running)

Answer (score 0):

If you create an line with this value and after that use these cell at formula bar the function will work.

If do you have many data. You can use the XY Chart Labeler that do this automatically.